# In The Hobbit film, how is Thorin's sword gathered with him by the giant eagle?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, adaptation-comparison

The sword is beyond his reach and yet is on him when the eagle gathers him up and away from the Orcs. Discontinuity in Middle-Earth...

Comment: Discontinuity in Peter Jackon's interpretation, more like - this never happened in the book.

Comment: Unanswerable movie making faux pas...aka, blooper :)

Comment: Perhaps he had it tied to his belt by a lanyard, like those loops on cameras.

Comment: 2Oldcat...And just didn't feel like using it on the Grey Orc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments have the answer, but I'll make an official answer so you can accept it.

The discontinuity you mention is only in the movie, in the book there is no such problem; the only (important) mention of Orcrist in the time before the Dwarves get saved off the trees by the Eagles is this 
(chapter: *Over Hill and Under Hill* ):

> Orcrist, too, had been saved; for Gandalf had brought it along as well, snatching it from one of the terrified guards.

Movies tend to run into problems when they add things to the story, and you just found one.

Comment: If an event has such lack of cause in a film, the script and direction are at fault. I'ld like a look at the story board. You are right, movie math - when adding doesn't add up.